# Conditionally include and rename file in wix

Tags: wix, installation, wix3.7

I have an installer that is including a third party library with a 32 and 64 bit version. The library comes with a 32-bit and 64-bit folder with the same file name. What I've done is renamed the files to have a distinct 32/64 name so that both can be included in the installer. I'm trying to set up in the `FILE` tag to conditionally include the file, but also to rename it back to its basic name of efxzlib.dll.

Is this possible with File? The `Name` attribute in `File` seems to rename the file at build time, not installation time. I'm trying to avoid seperate 32 and 64 bit installers since this DLL is the only unique 32/64 component. Is this best accomplished with a Managed Custom Action?

```
  <Component Id="CMP_EFX_ZLIB_32BIt" Guid="MY_GUID1">
    <Condition>
      <![CDATA[NOT(VersionNT64)]]>
    </Condition>
    <File Id="FILE_EFX_ZLIB_32BIt" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.EFX5LibraryBase32bit)\efxzlib32.dll" Name="efxzlib.dll" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="CMP_EFX_ZLIB_64BIt" Guid="{MY_GUID2}">
    <Condition>
      <![CDATA[VersionNT64]]>
    </Condition>
    <File Id="FILE_EFX_ZLIB_64BIt" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.EFX5LibraryBase64bit)\efxzlib64.dll" Name="efxzlib.dll" />
  </Component>
```

Comment: Your sample looks fine. What is not working with it?

Comment: wix builds an install package with both of those files. since they have the same name, it overwrites one of them. I want both files to exist in the installer as 32/64.dll, and only install one of the two, renaming the file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit unusual situation for typical Windows installer so I doubt this can be accomplished by WiX means. To do this in the right way there should be two installers one for 32bit system and the other one for 64bit system. So if you insist on your installation design you will end up with one 32bit installer that can install on both systems; the other way around is not suitable. So in such case I would recommend to do file renaming in post installation custom action. Remember that you need to obtain admin rights to do so. And also you will need to solve the problem with updates and with uninstallation and with re-installation.

In case of updates and re-installation, if this is applicable in your case, you will need again post installation custom action.

In case of uninstallation you will need either pre-installation step that will rename the file back to its origin or this custom action can delete the file, or you can enforce the folder deletion in XML. Otherwise the file will remain on the disk even though the application is uninstalled.

This is quite a complex task, which is durable however. Or please reconsider the 2 installers option.